# Why does Apache Cordova not support Linux Desktop?

Tags: linux, cordova

I have see recently this project to develop multiplatform applications, I see all major mobile platforms, and MAC OS X and Windows Desktop but, why no Linux Desktop support?

Comment: You would be better off asking the developers of Apache Cordova than asking this question here.

Comment: I just added the [phonegap] tag, as this technology is currently much better known by this name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you may have different GUI platforms on linux. Linux doesn't always come with a windowing system.

If you want to build a desktop application for linux using Cordova, then you probably want [Cordova for QT](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-qt).

*Disclaimer : I never tried Cordova for QT and I have no idea of its maturity.*

Comment: Thanks, but its a lot dissapointing to hear that. Also Miguel de Icaza (gnome co-founder) has same point of view. I will check Cordova for QT.